# Python while loop date iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

I currently have a script which takes a date and iterates from a certain date to today's date. The output lists the days in hour increments until the current date.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the loop to stop at 2017-07-10 00:00:000 or in other words, the beginning of the current date, with no hour listed afterward. Note: Someone mentioned a while loop just a bit confused on the logic.

Here is the code I am using:

```
sys_date = dt.datetime.today()#.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
Last_RT = Audit_Log.RUN_TIME_END.max()

#Looping through every hr until current date
for r in arrow.Arrow.range('hour', Last_RT, sys_date):
    print r.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

Output:

```
- 2017-07-09 00:00:00
- 2017-07-09 01:00:00
- 2017-07-09 02:00:00
- 2017-07-09 03:00:00
- 2017-07-09 04:00:00
- 2017-07-09 05:00:00

 ....................
- 2017-07-09 15:00:00
- 2017-07-09 16:00:00
- 2017-07-09 17:00:00
- 2017-07-09 18:00:00
- 2017-07-09 19:00:00
- 2017-07-09 20:00:00
- 2017-07-09 21:00:00
- 2017-07-09 22:00:00
- 2017-07-09 23:00:00
- 2017-07-10 00:00:00
- 2017-07-10 01:00:00
- 2017-07-10 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

use the floor method in arrow

```
start = arrow.now().replace(days=-5).floor('day')
end = arrow.now().floor('day')

#Looping through every hr until current date
for r in arrow.Arrow.range('hour', start, end):
    print r.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

That should give you the beginning of the day.

```
2017-07-05 00:00:00
2017-07-05 01:00:00
2017-07-05 02:00:00
...
2017-07-09 21:00:00
2017-07-09 22:00:00
2017-07-09 23:00:00
2017-07-10 00:00:00
```

**EDIT**

On a general note I very rarely run into an instance where I need both `arrow` and the built in `datetime` package. I use arrow unless it is absolutely necessary to use the builtin.

Comment: Hey Adam, thank you very much for your help. I am new to programming and therefore many times I just go off of my leads. Thank you for introducing me to the floor method. As well as the other tip on arrow and DateTime. Much appreciated a noob.

Comment: All is good. Just mark the question as answered :) points are always nice!

Comment: @victoAguilar so was my answer the one you were looking for?